# Is CDMA more secure than LTE or GSM?

Tags: wireless, digital-communications, telecommunications, security, spread-spectrum

I know that this question is very direct, but I was curious to know why is it that in defense applications, CDMA is preferred over LTE? Is CDMA more secure than LTE and hence more difficult to intercept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LTE (and GSM I believe) uses OFDM (orthogonal frequency division multiplexing) and simulataneously transmits several different "carriers" each containing a fraction of the full data bits. Upon reception, these demodulated fractions are then combined to restore the original (and full) data.

This means that each "carrier" is detectable in its own right. Compare this with CDMA where one of the significant military benefits is that any one particular "carrier" has a power that is close to or below the local ambient noise level in that part of the spectrum.

> I was curious to know why in defense applications CDMA is being
>   preferred over LTE

This immediately means that unless you know most of the frequencies used in a CDMA transmission you will likely not be able to detect the presense of a transmission.

Comment: Gsm does not use OFDM. If I remember correctly, it's only GMSK and PSK.

Comment: @AndrejaKo thanks for your input - I bow to your superior knowledge on this.